# Problems reading text file - non-breaking space character

Tags: c#, .net, string, character-encoding

I am trying to read some text file with the following line:

```
"WE BUY  : 10 000.00 USD"
```

First I have opened this file in binary editor and the 13th character (or 12th by 0-based C# indexing) (thousand separator) is "160 code in decimal" or "A0 code in hex" in Windows-1251 encoding.

However after I read this line into string using `File.ReadAllLines`
in the debugger I can see the the character now has 65533 code.

"lines[9][12]   65533 '�'   char"

The default encoding **Encoding.Default** for my PC is "Windows-1251".

How come?

UPDATE

Tryed open the file with UTF-8 encoding, still the same result.

UPDATE 2

The problem is that file encoding is 8bit but the debugger shows for 8bit character 'A0' 16 bit value of 65533.

Comment: Is it ansi? What is input file encoding? The problem may be because you use different ways to see the same character and in one place it's 13'th, and in other - not 13'th.

Comment: Lex, How do I know? Looks like 'Windows 1251'

Comment: Try opening with some extended text editor as Notepad ++. Or open with VS and then save using "save with encoding" where specify ansi. There can be UTF -7 encoding that is not so native as UTF-8 and can make some inpacts.

Comment: What do you mean under 'ansi'? if ansi is standard code page than it is Windows-1251 as mentioned.

Comment: It's not Encoding.Default for my PC is "Windows-1251". It's just an encoding for the file. And looks like that's the problem. As I understand you copied or got this value from some output. After that in editor you see whitespace, that replaces bad char in original file for viewing.

Comment: Yeap I got the file from somewhere. So I assume the encoding is 'Windows-1251' cause I can open it as 'Windows-1251' and see the text. Now I will post two screenshow for you. I hope it will help

Comment: Try saving it with that encoding. Or try using Richards approach:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one argument [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) will assume the input is UTF-8, whatever the system default encoding.

For anything else you need to specify the encoding:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(name));
```

You can get `name` from your `Encoding.Default.WebName` ("Windows-1252" is what I get here, but check locally).

Comment: Cool thanks. I was incorrectly assuming that File.ReadAllLines(fileName) is equal to File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.Default) while in fact it is UTF-8, just checked in Reflector. So my problem was that 8bit encoding was opened with Unicode. Problem fixed.